# Any reason why aspnetzero doesnt allow tenancy name starting with number eg. 7tests

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

Any reason why aspnetzero doesnt allow tenancy name starting with number eg. 7tests. Is 7tests not a valid tenancy name?

Comment: You can try. Generally, identifiers shouldn't start with a number.

Answer (score 2):

This is just for precaution!

1- ASP.NET Zero allows to create separate database for a tenant. And the database name becomes the tenancy name. And ASP.NET Zero uses ASP.NET Boilerplate under the hood.

2- ASP.NET Boilerplate framework is not sticked to any database system. It uses Entity Framework and supports all the databases, EF supports. So, not to experience any issues when creating a new database on different database systems, it's not allowed on purpose. Currently the regex is declared in `Abp.Zero.Common` library > `AbpTenantBase.TenancyNameRegex`. Because it's  `const` you cannot change it...

But there's a way of achieving this.
You can create your own TenantManager and override the virtual `ValidateTenancyNameAsync(string tenancyName)` method in  `AbpTenantManager` class. And one last thing to change is the UI validations. Set your own regex on UI validations.

Finally you can use the below regex that passes database name restrictions

```
"[0-9a-zA-Z$_]+"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will check by overriding ValidateTenancyNameAsync method and let you know if that works.

Answer (score 0):

Variable name cannot start with numbers.

The name can contain letters, digits, and the underscore character (_).

The first character of the name must be a letter. The underscore is also a legal first character, but its use is not recommended at the beginning of a name. An underscore is often used with special commands, and it's sometimes hard to read.

Case matters (that is, upper- and lowercase letters). C# is case-sensitive; thus, the names count and Count refer to two different variables.

C# keywords can't be used as variable names. Recall that a keyword is a word that is part of the C# language. (A complete list of the C# keywords can be found in Appendix B, "C# Keywords.")

Comment: its not a variable name.

Comment: can you point me to location - where it is used as variable name?